# Javascript - replace same occurence in a string value with an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I would like to replace the occurences of "?" with the values in an array

Example :

```
var s = "hello ? , my name is ?";
```

I would like to use something like that

```
var result= s.replace('?',['john','david']); /** does not work **/
console.log(result) /** "hello john, my name is david" **/
```

Comment: Consider using a RegEx as the "needle"? `/\?/gi` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Comment: This will replace each '?' with array, not with single name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this by using [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression and a function. You'll also need an outside variable to increment. I called it `i`.

```js
var s = "hello ? , my name is ?";

var i = 0;
var result = s.replace(/\?/g, function() {
  return ['john','david'][i++];
});

console.log(result);
```